# Updated "Google Drive for Desktop" app makes compiling extremely slow?

Tags: compiling

I recently updated from Google's "Backup and Sync" to the new "Google Drive for Desktop," and now compiling tex files that are in my Google Drive folder is so slow that I can't work on anything.  Each line in the console during compiling takes like 3-5 seconds to appear (and a standard, 120 page document with no special figures or anything fancy takes like 10 mins to compile), whereas before updating the whole compilation would take less than a second.  Can anyone offer some guidance/advice?

I use TexShop 4.67 on a 2019 Mac mini and a 2020 M1 MacBook Pro running Big Sur 11.5.2, and through work we have to use Google to backup to the cloud.  Both computers have the same issue since updating the Google software.

I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the new Google Drive acts like an external drive?  Even storing/syncing the relevant folders locally on my actual hard drive doesn't solve this problem.

If I copy a tex file to my desktop and recompile, it's very fast and works as expected.

Anyway, my professional life has ground to a halt and I don't know what to do (other than obvious things like copy files to my Mac hard drive, work on them, then put them back in the Google Drive, but that's a recipe for disaster as far as I'm concerned!).  Thank you very much for any insight you might have!

P.P.H.